# Forget a certain revision from the repository (BZR)

Tags: bazaar

i have a bzr repository with revision number 701 and some time ago on revision number 680 i committed some code that changes every file in the repository (i.e. a source code formatter changes every file ) now i want to have the old formatting with out missing the changes i made after revision 680

how can i forget revision number 680 the one that changes every file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1st way: `bzr merge -r680..679`, but you have to be ready to resolve many conflicts in the places where you made changes after re-formatting.

2nd way: use `bzr rebase` command from bzr-rewrite (former bzr-rebase) plugin.

Comment: thank you,i have seen but i want some one sure ,you make it crystal clear 
Thank you,bialix

Comment: one additional thing how can this be done if i want the only .THIS extensions from the source

Comment: @jspeshu I don't understand your question about .THIS

Comment: i mean when you do the forget command there will be conflicts on the files that were modified after the change so that will create 3 files for each conflicting files with extensions .THIS , .OTHER ,and .BASE so since i removed only a revision that only changes the formating 
=> i only want the resolution to be made by taking files with .THIS extension

Comment: @jspeshu if you're using bzr 2.2 then you can run the following command: `bzr resolve --take-this` see http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/bzr.2.2/en/user-reference/resolve-help.html#resolve . In bzr 2.1 and earlier you should just copy foo.ext.THIS over foo.THIS and run `bzr resolve` after that.